# Wordpress child pages not working

Tags: php, child-pages

I am creating a wordpress CMS and I have added multiple pages under one parent page. I am generating the links for all the child pages of a page and then when user clicks on the links, they should be able to open the child page. How ever when I click on the links, the index page is opened and no child page content is displayed. May be it is due to the use of the .htaccess file. I dont have any knowledge of htaccess. Any help?

```
<?php
            $pages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc' ) );

            foreach ($pages as $page) {
            ?>

                <div class="contentarea">
                <div class="leftside"><img alt="" src="http://zom.jtechsolutions.co/wp-content/themes/zone/images/pic_1.jpg" /></div>
                <div class="rightside">
                <h2><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></h2>
                <?php echo substr(strip_tags($page->post_content),0,50); ?>

                <a href="<?php echo get_post_permalink($page->ID); ?>">Read More...</a>

                </div>
                </div>

            <?php

                }
            ?>
```

.htaccess

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Can you post a link to the problem page?

Comment: @s_ha_dum http://zom.jtechsolutions.co/services/

Comment: Those links look right. Unfortunately your theme is not using `body_class` so I can't tell what template is loading.

Comment: What's your permalink structure?

Comment: The clue will be inspecting the URLs as HTML then copy pasting them into a browser. If they look well-formed but go to the wrong page there’s a permalink problem, if the links are not well formed there’s a PHP problem. If the latter then print_r everything in sight.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_permalink), get_post_permalink applies to custom post types. I don't think you are using a custom post type, right?

Instead, try `get_page_link( $page->ID )`

Comment: I used it, it is not working either. http://zom.jtechsolutions.co/services/ this is the link

Comment: Your links are correct. htaccess is correct. There's something else awry. Have you perhaps edited your page.php to be the home page?

Comment: Are you using Apache or NGINX?

Links may be related to your site setup in NGINX.